# Formula not being rendered

Tags: bug, mathjax

The following latex code :

```
J(\theta) = -1/m \left[ \sum\limits_{i=1}^m \sum\limits_{k=1}^K y_k ^(^i^) log (\:h\theta(x ^i))k  + (1 - y_k^(^i^)) \: log (1 - (h\theta(x ^i))k) \right]

+

\newline
\newline

\lambda / 2m \sum\limits_{l=1}^{L-1}  \sum\limits_{i=1}^{sl} \sum\limits_{j=1}^{sl+1} (\theta_{ji}^{(l)})^2
```

produces:

[image]

on http://www.sciweavers.org/free-online-latex-equation-editor

But on math stackexchange this formula is not rendered ? Should I escape some symbols?

Update :

$$ J(\theta) = -1/m \left[ \sum\limits_{i=1}^m \sum\limits_{k=1}^K y_k^{(i)} log (\:h\theta(x ^i))k  + (1 - y_k^{(i)}) \: log (1 - (h\theta(x ^i))k) \right]
\\
+
\\
\lambda / 2m \sum\limits_{l=1}^{L-1}  \sum\limits_{i=1}^{sl} \sum\limits_{j=1}^{sl+1} (\theta_{ji}^{(l)})^2 $$

Comment: 1. No empty lines in math environment. 2. `\newline` should be replaced with `\\ `. 3. `y_k ^(^i^)` is invalid, did you mean `y_k^{(i)}`?

Comment: @Daniel Fischer thank you, that worked except I used \\ for new lines as your latex for new line did not render

Comment: That was a markdown failure. I typed backtick-backslash-backslash-backtick and didn't notice that Markdown interpreted one of the backslashes as an escape for the closing backtick.